# Why can't Java ArrayList be accessed by unique key?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I was passing the [Java test](http://www.indiabix.com/online-test/java-programming-test/61) and came across the following question (№8):

```
Which statement is true for the class java.util.ArrayList?

    A.  The elements in the collection are ordered.
    B.  The collection is guaranteed to be immutable.
    C.  The elements in the collection are guaranteed to be unique.
    D.  The elements in the collection are accessed using a unique key.
```

I've answered A and it is true. But why D is not true? I open the source of ArrayList and find the following chunk of code:

```
/**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA will be expanded to
 * DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

Since, we can access to any element of an ArrayList using a unique key (index of element). Why does such reasoning is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed right: a list can be accesed using a unique key; the restriction is that you don't have an arbitrary choice of key.

In fact, maps are also known as "associative arrays", emphasizing the equivalence between a `List` and a `Map`.

As to why this wasn't accepted in your exam, it is due to lack of care when writing exam questions. From personal experience I can attest that *a lot* of care is needed to get an exam right.

Comment: An index is a reference to a location within a structure. A key would need to be "searched for" within the structure. While each index in an ArrayList is "unique", it does not satisfy the "search structure for key" normal meaning of a key.

Comment: Just because "an index is a reference to a location within a structure" does not in any way stop it from *also* being a key. The definition of "key" you are advocating is too concrete and is certainly not "normal". A map could be implemented such that no search is performed to reach the key; for example a `Map<Integer, Object>` could be implemented with pure arrays, storing values at indices corresponding to keys.

Comment: Actually, it IS normal to refer to a Key as something that must be matched (through a search), while an Index is somewhere.

Comment: You can repeat that any number of times, but that will not make it true. In fact, direct access without search is the holy grail of a perfect map imlementation.

Comment: Does the phrase "element at index 3 of a sparse array" make any sense to you? According to your definitions, it doesn't make sense because a sparse array cannot generally be implemented such that an index corresponds to a location within a structure.

Comment: yes I agree with Marko, don't mix index with that one deeper inside the memory buffer location . That's just too abstract for a simple question.

Answer (score 2):

> The elements in the collection are accessed using a unique key.

That would be describing a `Map` instead of a `List`. I would have asked myself the same question, and indeed the array index can be thought of as a "key". However since such a key would be implicitly unique, the last statement seems more descriptive of a map structure.

Comment: I think about it. Do you think that an `index` is rather different concept from a `key`?

Comment: A key is usually associated with a map or table, or any collection of pairs. A list is not really an associative array so they should be different concepts. However nothing prevents you from thinking of an index as a "key". It depends on the context of the question.

Comment: What is the conceptual difference between a `Map<Integer, Object>` and a `List<Object>`? Both map integer keys to arbitrary values.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No conceptual difference but you already have two different classes. The map has an explicit key in it, while the list has the index as an "implicit" key.

Comment: The conceptual difference is about how one accesses a value: an index lets you access a value from a location; a key requires you to search the structure to retrieve a value.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of ArrayList may be accessed by their index into the list, not a key.

You asked why the elements cannot be accessed by a "unique key" ... the answer to that is that the language definition does not allow it.  (You may be mistaking the index for a key.)

**Elaboration**: an index is NOT a key. An index specifies a location within a structure, a key requires one to search a structure for the value of that key. You are getting confused because the indecies are each unique ... but they are not keys

Comment: No .. and index is NOT a key. An index specifies a location within a structure, a key requires one to search a structure for the value of that key. You are getting confused because the indecies are each unique ... but they are not keys.

Comment: You are mixing up implementation from abstraction. An index is a key into an array. "Key" is not a technical term related to map implementation, it is a concept which implies that there exists a *mapping* between a set of *keys* and a set of *values*. The set of `int`s does certainly stand up to that definition.

Answer (score 1):

`unique key` simply means an `index` representing element of java.util.ArrayList , there are no 2 different elements have same `index`. Right !?

Comment: No a key is used to search a structure in order to find a value; an index is a location reference within a structure from which to get a value.  Simply being unique does not imply that a unique KEY is used.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII, yes true but `unique key` doesn't suit `element` or `value'. Probably it's just about words misunderstanding :D

Comment: Yes ... it IS about language!  A "Key" is used for a search, an "index" is used for a location.  Fortunately language specificity is one of the requirements for programming.

Comment: your term always makes me corious somehow (I believe there's nothing wrong with it), but trust me that I really understand your point, we have different terms but we refer to the same thing  :D, that's why with all my respect ,I give you plus one on your answer below ..

Answer (score 1):

When you use a key/value, you can access the value by looking up the same key no matter how other entries in the Map have changed.

An index is not a key as it can change each time you add or remove an entry. If you keep deleting from the start of a List you can access every element of the list with `get(0)` which is clearly not unique to the value.

Comment: Uniqueness has never applied to the temporal dimension. At any arbitrary state of the list there is a unique mapping from index to value. When you delete an element, the mapping changes, but the uniqueness property stays invariant. Maintaining the stability of key-value mapping over structural mutation events can be seen as an *additional* feature of a `Map`.